# Best practices for declaring functions inside jquery ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I haven't found a good reference for declaring my own functions inside the

```
jquery.ready(function(){});
```

I want to declare them so they are inside the same scope of the ready closure.  I don't want to clutter the global js namespace so I don't want them declared outside of the ready closure because they will be specific to just the code inside.

So how does one declare such a function...and I'm not referring to a custom jquery extension method/function...just a regular 'ol function that does something trivial say like:

```
function multiple( a, b ){ 
    return a * b; 
}
```

I want to follow the jquery recommendation and function declaration syntax.  I can get it to work by just declaring a function like the multiply one above...but it doesn't look correct to me for some reason so I guess I just need some guidance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I believe that you would be okay just declaring the function inside the ready() closure, but here you can be a bit more explicit about the local scoping:

```
jQuery.ready(function() {

     var myFunc = function() {

           // do some stuff here

     };

     myFunc();


});
```

Comment: Bingo, this is what i was looking for because it's more clear about the scope of the function and follows the jquery syntax better it seams. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: Sorry if it's a stupid comment but this answer confuses me.
Shouldn't the function call rather be "myFunc();" instead of "myFunction();" ?

Answer (score 9):

It might sound simple but you just ... declare the function. Javascript allows functions to have inner functions.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
   alert("hello! document is ready!");

   function multiply(a, b) {
       return a * b;
   }

   alert("3 times 5 is " + multiply(3, 5));
});
```

Answer (score 7):

I have a StartUp function, and I use it as printed bellow:

```
function StartUp(runnable)
{
    $(document).ready(runnable.run);
}

var ExternalLinks =
{
    run: function()
    {
        $('a[rel="external"]').bind('click', ExternalLinks.click);
    },
    click: function(event)
    {
        open(this.href);
        return false;
    }
}
StartUp(ExternalLinks);

var ConfirmLinks =
{
    run: function()
    {
        $('a.confirm').bind('click', ConfirmLinks.click);
    },
    click: function(event)
    {
        if (!confirm(this.title)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
StartUp(ConfirmLinks);
```

My web sites are modular, so every module has N actions and every action can have a .js file, so I just write function and call it with StartUp(...functionName...)