# Define function inside the module in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to define a function attachPicker can be called like:

```
(function(){
  $.fn.tagPicker = function(source){
    this.attachPicker();
  }
})(jQuery);
```

I tried:

```
(function(){
    $.fn.tagPicker = function(source){
      this.attachPicker();
      //define attachPicker
      $.fn.attachPicker = function(){
        //code here
      }
    }
 })(jQuery);


(function(){
      $.fn.tagPicker = function(source){
          this.attachPicker();
          //define attachPicker
          this.attachPicker = function(){
            //code here
          }
      }
})(jQuery);
```

Both threw out

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'attachPicker'
```

If I did

```
(function(){
      $.fn.tagPicker = function(source){
        this.attachPicker();
      }
      $.fn.attachPicker() = function(){ //codes here };
})(jQuery);
```

It worked. But I want to define attachPicker inside tagPicker so that it can access the source. Anyone can explain why the ones I tried didn't work and give me any suggestions? Of course I knew I can pass source as argument if defining attachPicker outside.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: change order of functions so `attachPicker` exists when you call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before using any function you should define that function

Try this code

```
(function(){
      $.fn.tagPicker = function(source){

          //define attachPicker
          this.attachPicker = function(){
            //code here
          }
          this.attachPicker();
      }
})(jQuery);
```

You can test here:
http://jsfiddle.net/s23py/
also you can call it by an object:
http://jsfiddle.net/s23py/2/

Comment: These URLs will clarify you more `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587954/best-practices-for-declaring-functions-inside-jquery-ready-function` and `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887408/javascript-function-declaration-and-evaluation-order`