# JS Toggle (display) text the simplest way

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle

I'm trying toggle to change visibility(display) the text in next way http://jsfiddle.net/xL8hyoye/ . It doesn't work, but should work.

HTML code here:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>
```

JS code here:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

> (code from this source
>   http://blog.movalog.com/a/javascript-toggle-visibility/)

---

Solved when replacing :

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
```

By :

```
toggle_visibility = function(id) {
```

(thanks to Zakaria Acharki).

Reason of this is visible variable area and, in first case - JSFiddle extern libraries settings(after set no library you need to set 'No wrap in head'). 
As amit.rk3 said here the similar theme

[Inline event handler not working in JSFiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

And here the proof(js and html code were not changed, only 'No wrap in head' settings) http://jsfiddle.net/xL8hyoye/3/

Comment: duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfiddle)

Comment: "I'm trying toggle to change visibility(display) the text in next way", what's that "next way"??

Comment: @Amit.rk3 this is not a duplicate of the question whose link you have provided!

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary OP updated the question. Check the first fiddle he posted. [http://jsfiddle.net/xL8hyoye/](http://jsfiddle.net/xL8hyoye/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your function declaration, See the [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xL8hyoye/1/) :

```
toggle_visibility = function(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it doesn't work on the first click? And how the declaration of the function is fixing this issue?

Comment: Here i'll try to find the answer about two clicks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372615/js-one-click-tooglenot-two-clicks-default-value-of-toogled-element.
What about reason of the declaration - here some information about that  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431351/simple-example-doesnt-work-on-jsfidd‌​le

Comment: Hi bro Take a look [Here - 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/587954/best-practices-for-declaring-functions-inside-jquery-ready-function) and [Here - 2](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/) also [Here - 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480756/jquery-function-declaration-explanation) that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the initial CSS display value of the div element (by default it is set to block, but not accessible to JS).

```js
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo" style="display: block;">This is foo</div>
```

or check if style.display is empty

```js
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>
```

Comment: The same code wouldn't work in jsfiddle without undefault option 'no wrap in head', it was the reason http://jsfiddle.net/xL8hyoye/6/ and http://jsfiddle.net/xL8hyoye/7/ compare

Comment: but what if you remove ' style="display: block;" from this snippet example. Would that work?