# JS one-click Toggle (not two clicks) - default value of toggled element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why here we need to **click two times** (http://jsfiddle.net/xL8hyoye/4/):

html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>
```

css: `#foo {display: none;}`

js:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'none')
      e.style.display = 'block';
   else
      e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

---

When here only by **one click** text disappears (http://jsfiddle.net/xL8hyoye/5/):

html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo" style='display:none'>This is foo</div> <!-- add display style here -->
```

css: `<!-- delete ccs here -->`

js:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'none')
      e.style.display = 'block';
   else
      e.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Note that a DIV by default has a display effectively of "block" style but it returns "" as the style is a part of the element definition and not an attribute (yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the style.display property is empty

```js
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display == '')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here to toggle visibility of element #foo</a>
<div id="foo">This is foo</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `.style` is looking at the direct inline style of the element other than it's CSS style sheet. So for example, it will work if it looked like so:

```
<div id="foo" style="display: none;">This is foo</div>
```

[**Here is an example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xL8hyoye/12/). Otherwise the `.style` isn't defined when placed in the CSS. In the second example the first click defines `e.style.display`, then it works normally afterwards. That is why it takes two clicks.

Another way to fix it is add an `else` since `e.style.display` to change it to what you want, assuming the element is hidden at the start:

```
if(e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
else if( e.style.display == 'none' )
    e.style.display = 'block';
else 
    e.style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 2):

In the getElementById() documentation they state :

```
Document.getElementById()
```

> Returns a reference to the element by its ID.

See it here : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

So your javascript code is only assessing HTML **Without CSS** on the first iteration in particular.
I guess that's why first it goes to `else` and on the second click it gives `e.style.display` the value `block` ; because `e.style.display` has `none` as a value then.

Try using a different method than getElementById() if ever.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved changing the order in your `if-else` statement, like:

```
if(e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
else
    e.style.display = 'block';
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/xL8hyoye/9/)

Note: Your initial code don't work because the initial value of `e.style.display` is `""` instead `none` :)

Comment: hi, I tested this and foo style.display returns "none" to me, can you confirm this?

Comment: Check [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/xL8hyoye/13/), I set an alert so you can see what is the value of `e.style.display` with every click. First time it's empty :)

Comment: I prefer not to have a dependence on code sequence myself - avoids changes breaking code later.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I agree with you, but this is a simple fix ;)